# How to call functions when required, each containing PHPUnit ascertions

Tags: php, phpunit

I can create a single php file that uses PHPunit for assertions inside one function, inside a class. Is it possible to call functions, with each function containing an assertion?

(At the moment I'm only using Xampp and notepad++ on Windows)

```
fileA.php:
=============
require_once ‘fileA.php’;
testA():
testB();
testC();


fileB.php:
==========

class availabletests extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase 
{

   function testA()
   {  $this->assertEquals(2,1+1); }

   function testB()
   {  $this->assertEquals(20,1+1); } 

   function testC()
   {  $this->assertEquals(8,1+1); } 

}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Generally you would run unit tests using the phpunit script: `$phpunit fileB.php`, and then it will give you verbose information about which tests failed and which assertions failed. To that extent, it's much better to have multiple test methods in a single file/class, as it's better for isolating each test case and allows you to look at each success/failure independently.

Answer (score 0):

Not only is it *possible* to have multiple test methods in a single unit test, it's actually how PHPUnit is designed to be used and is [preferable to putting multiple assertions into a single test](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/7829/94618). When your unit test runs via the [command line test runner](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html), this will be the output:

```
$ phpunit availabletests.php 
  PHPUnit 3.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann.

  .FF

  Time: 41 ms, Memory: 3.00Mb

  There were 2 failures:

  1) availabletests::testB
  Failed asserting that 2 matches expected 20.

  /home/gwallace/availabletests.php:10

  2) availabletests::testC
  Failed asserting that 2 matches expected 8.

  /home/gwallace/availabletests.php:13

  FAILURES!
  Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Failures: 2.
```

This isolates each test case and gives you verbose information on which test cases failed, and which assertions they failed on.